# How to Validate the password using regular expression with Special Symbols, Characters and Numeric in Java Script

Tags: javascript

below Syntax var re = /(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[.|*+(){}]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]*$)^([a-zA-Z0-9]{6,15})$/;
But it doesn't validate the special symbols?

Answer (score 0):

```
/(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[.|*+(){}\[\]]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]*$)^([a-zA-Z0-9.|*+(){}\[\]]{6,15})$/
```

Comment: Thanks, But It Doesn't take the Special Symbols
 I checked with this word: ABac134567]

Comment: Which special symbols do you want to allow exactly? Your question doesn't make it clear.